# READ Bearer in ISAPI DELPHI

Tags: delphi, authorization, bearer-token, isapi

I have ISAPI DLL project in  *Delphi 10.2*, i need to ***read ***all header items, exactly the Authorization Bearer to accept or not the POST request.
With exe DatasnapBroker, this is a success with this code

```
FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
  FServer.OnParseAuthentication := OnDoParseAuthentication;
```

and in the function **OnDoParseAuthentication**

```
procedure  TForm1.OnDoParseAuthentication(AContext: TIdContext; const AAuthType,
  AAuthData: String; var VUsername, VPassword: String; var VHandled: Boolean);


  function DoParseAuthentication(ASender: TIdContext; const AAuthType,
    AAuthData: String; var VUsername, VPassword: String): Boolean;
  var
    s,__BaseName, __GuidBase: String;
  begin
    Result := False;
    if TextIsSame(AAuthType, 'Basic') then begin
      with TIdDecoderMIME.Create do try
        s := DecodeString(AAuthData);
      finally Free; end;
      VUsername := Fetch(s, ':');
      VPassword := s;
      Result := True;
    end
    else if TextIsSame(AAuthType, 'Bearer') then
    begin
       with TIdDecoderMIME.Create do try
        s := DecodeString(AAuthData);
      finally Free; end;
      //decrypt jwt or oauth2.0 in my Tjwt.Decodejwt_Bearer class
      //for header / payload-data / signature
      //sur ISAPI uniquement ici, sur exe lors du create
      if Tjwt.Decodejwt_Bearer(AAuthData,__BaseName, __GuidBase) then
      begin
        //verifier et valider 
        Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;
begin
  VHandled := DoParseAuthentication(AContext, AAuthType, AAuthData, VUsername, VPassword);
end;
```

But, I don't know **how to read the authorization**, I always have empty in request.Authorization in **TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch**

if i have in my header :
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:811
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Content-Length: 396
Authorization: **Basic **VEVDSF......cCNG

- it's ok, request.Authorization = Basic ....

But if i write
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJS....Im

- it's KO, request.Authorization = ''

Comment: What is the length of bearer token? If you check implementation of `TISAPIRequest.GetFieldByNameA` in `Web.Win.IsapiHTTP.pas` you discover that header values are limited to 4095 bytes (excluding null terminator). After subtracting the length of `'Bearer '` prefix (7) you get 4088 as the maximum size of bearer token. Anything longer than that will be returned as an empty string.

Comment: indeed, you are right, it is a question of length, I tried with a few bytes, I have Beareer authorization, now my question how to do if my token is 6845 bytes, thank you

Comment: A 6kB token????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `Request` property of `TWebModule` in an ISAPI web application is an instance of `TISAPIRequest` class from `Web.Win.IsapiHTTP`. It implements reading the value of `Authorization` property via `GetServerVariable` function of [`EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525658(v=vs.90)) structure. The getter ends up in `TISAPIRequest.GetFieldByNameA` method, which is only able to read up to 4095 bytes of data from single HTTP header. This limits the bearer token to 4088 bytes after you subtract the size of `'Bearer '` prefix from it.

To workaround this limitation of `TISAPIRequest` you can implement your own extension method for reading request data:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Web.Win.IsapiHTTP;

type
  TISAPIRequestHelper = class helper for TISAPIRequest
  public
    function GetServerVariable(const Name: UTF8String): UTF8String;
  end;

function TISAPIRequestHelper.GetServerVariable(const Name: UTF8String): UTF8String;
var
  Size: DWORD;
begin
  // calculate size
  Size := 0;
  ECB.GetServerVariable(ECB.ConnID, PUTF8Char(Name), nil, Size);
  if Size <= 1 then
  begin
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  // get the actual variable value
  SetLength(Result, Size - 1);
  if not ECB.GetServerVariable(ECB.ConnID, PUTF8Char(Name), PUTF8Char(Result), Size) then
    Result := '';
end;
```

To access the `Authorization` header you would then call:

```
string((Request as TISAPIRequest).GetServerVariable('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'));
```